# Apache Virtual Server accept request from every domain

Tags: apache, subdomain, server, virtualhost

I am developing a website builder and I need Apache to accept request from every domain, like example2.com , example3.com , etc.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
  ServerName builder.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible? I know that I can create a vhost.conf file for each domain and enable it with a2ensite. But a wildcard that handle every request should be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive all requests from all website, you must add the wildcard to ServerAlias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
  ServerName builder.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  ServerAlias *     #Add this line
</VirtualHost>
```